# In the Twilio video JavaScript API, how can I get the SID of the local participant?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have this code:

```js
      room = await Video.connect(token, { name: roomName });
      room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
      room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
```

It calls `participantConnected` for everyone except the user whose browser this is. How do I get the local participant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the SID of the local participant in the following way:

```
room.localParticipant.sid
```